# Power series method to solve Airy’s differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Using power series method, solve [Airy’s equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html) 
$$y′′+ xy = 0.$$

How do I start solving this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assume that $y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, then you need to find $a_n$.

Comment: So we get $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=0$$?

Comment: Now come up with a recursion relation for the coefficients (and relate this back to something you know if you can).

Comment: @simon90 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

$$\tag 1 y''+ x y = 0$$

Solve this using Power Series.

We assume:

$$y = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m$$

Thus we have:

$$y'' = \sum_{m=2}^\infty m(m-1)a_mx^{m-2}$$

Substituting into the $(1)$, we get:

$$\sum_{m=2}^\infty m(m-1)a_mx^{m-2} + \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^{m+1} = 0$$

Aligning starting points for the series, we have:

$$2a_2 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty ((m+1)(m+2)a_{m+2} + a_{m-1})x^m = 0$$

Now equate terms to zero and solve for the $a's$.

Comment: Thanks, so do we get $y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$, where
$$y_1=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^nn![2\cdot5\cdot\cdot\cdot(3n-1)]}x^{3n}$$
$$y_2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^nn![1\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot(3n+1)]}x^{3n+1}$$

Comment: @simon90 Indeed!

Comment: @simon90: I did not write in that compact form, but it looks good. Regards

Comment: Yes indeed...Brutal week. But savor the weekend ahead!

Comment: can anyone tell about the zeros of the solution?