# Zeros of the solution of Airy's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

Consider the Airy's equation $$y''(x)+xy(x)=0,\ x>0.$$ It solutions are given here [Solution of $y''+xy=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197528/solution-of-yxy-0).

I am looking for the number of zeros of its solutions. Whether they are finite or finite? Can I deduce something from the solutions? Please help.

Comment: Have you read [DLMF 9.9](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.9) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has infinite zeros. See [Airy Function Zeros](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctionZeros.html) for references.